# Check number of requests sent by all clients

Tags: haproxy

I'm currently implementing my new conf for haproxy and I would like to create an ACL based on the number of requests sent.

When I read the documentation there is some check like that but it's dedicated to a specific IP, as:

```
src_conn_cur  
src_conn_rate 
sc0_http_err_rate()  
sc0_http_req_rate()
```

Is there a solution to get all the request sent from every source addresses at the same time? If I reach a specific number of request I want to redirect the users to another backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fe_req_rate](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#7.3.2-fe_req_rate) fetch.

You can use this to direct users to another backend like this if the global number of requests per second on the current frontend is above 100 / sec:

```
use_backend overflow if { fe_req_rate gt 100 }
use_backend default
```